# Installshield installscript setup terminates after UAC prompt

Tags: installation, installscript

I have an InstallShield InstallScript (no MSI) installer which basically works quite fine.

On a specific machine, the installer immediately terminates after the UAC prompt for elevated execution. What I expect is that the installer is loaded and offers to install the prerequisites.

What I have tried so far:

- Observed the task manager detail tab and saw that the installer is listed for a split-second, then is gone.
- Put a log message in the OnBegin() callback, but this is way too late.
- Deactivated virus scanners.
- Checked windows event logs -- no related record found
- Attempted to execute the installer with logging using /V"L*v c:\file.log" -- no log file is written
- Attempted to execute the installer with logging using /debuglog -- no log file is written

I have already spent days with the problem, and I don't know where to look for any hint what is going on here, not to mention how to fix the problem.

Anything that can help here is highly appreciated -- Thanks!

Comment: Maybe not a true solution, but at least a workaround: Create a new user with admin privileges and run the setup installer => works.

So apparently there is something wrong inside the user profile.

Answer (score 1):

Installshield relies on win32 libraries. I had a similar case and below are the possible solutions

1)Please try to apply all the available windows updates.

2)Try to repair windows system files.Reference https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/system-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files/bc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93

3)Try installing the executable after creating new user account.

Comment: This is basically what I did (see my comment above). However, I am not sure we can count "creating a new user account" as a true solution ;) -- Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah! it's not a true solution. Since install-shield is tightly coupled to win32 libraries any failure in system libraries may impact installer. Make a post in [https://community.flexera.com/t5/Revenera-Community/ct-p/Revenera_Community](customer community) @Reinhard Mayr,  it may help you to resolve the issue.